# New UI Button misunderstood pointer click and pointer down action

Tags: user-interface, button, unity-game-engine

I am making a game with ui controller. i use button to make that controller.

[image: Controller]

in the picture, i have "A" button. when my "character" facing npc, i want to talk with that npc with click that button. when dialogue is over, i need to close the dialogue box using this button too. 
but what i got is, this button clicked over and over, so the first dialogue is skipped, and the dialogue which is showed up is the third or maybe the fourth dialog.

i attach event trigger on this button. 
[image: event trigger that attached in "A" button]

and this is my code that is attached on that event trigger

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class aButtonScript : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start(){
    }

    public void click(){
        if(walkingScript.walking.interact == true)
        {
            loadGame.loadSave.objPrince.GetComponent<plantingScript>().aButton = false;
            loadGame.loadSave.objPrince.GetComponent<walkingScript>().aButton = true;
        }
    }

    public void clicked()
    {
        if(plantingScript.planting.toolBoxCanvas != null)
        {
            loadGame.loadSave.objPrince.GetComponent<plantingScript>().aButton = false;
            choosingTools.ct.setTool();
        }

    }

    public void unclicked()
    {
        loadGame.loadSave.objPrince.GetComponent<plantingScript>().aButton = false;
    }
}
```

well, this is my first time making a game. hope whoever who read this question can help me. sorry for my bad english. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure, but I've had similar problems when using `GetMouseButton` instead of `GetMouseButtonDown`. The first one triggers for each frame the button is pressed. Looking at your UI setup it seems you acivate the script when the button is pressed, for each frame it is pressed, and finally when it is released.

Comment: what should i do so the script do not activate the first trigger but it activate what it should be. if the condition is for click, i want the script activate the click mode, and so pressed. i am really confused.T__T

Comment: Have a look at your Event Trigger. It got one case for button clicked, button unclicked and one for released. You want something to happen when the button is clicked, but you have setup your Event Trigger for all of the three instances.